# Ordering a string containing an integer inside SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below content inside a table in SQL

[image]

I tried to order by title but I didn't work, is there any SQL statement to use so I can order by the number inside `InterSciences Competition`?

Comment: do substring of the number part and use in order

Comment: You need to extract the integer part.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: What should happen if there's no number inside the parenthesis? Or if the there are two records with the same number but different text?

Answer (score 4):

You can try like following query.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT title, 
                Cast(Substring(title, Charindex('(', title) + 1, 
                     Charindex(')', title) - 
                     Charindex('(', title) - 1) 
                     AS INT) AS OC 
         FROM   yourtable) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
ORDER  BY oc
```

In above query, the number between brackets is extracted and converted to `INT` for ordering.

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/WOQH80082)

Comment: or you can just use that on order by clause.
ORDER BY Cast(Substring(title, Charindex('(', title) + 1, 
                     Charindex(')', title) - 
                     Charindex('(', title) - 1) 
                     AS INT)

Comment: @hims056 haha, now I see the query you wrote, I did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Using `SUBSTRING()` and `PATINDEX()`, this ordering is possible:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (TestVal VARCHAR (20));
INSERT INTO @TestTable (TestVal) VALUES ('Test (1)'), ('Test (10)'), ('Test (2)');

SELECT TestVal 
FROM @TestTable 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(TestVal, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', TestVal), LEN(TestVal) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', TestVal)) AS INT),
         LEFT(TestVal, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', TestVal) - 2)
```

Output:

```
TestVal
---------
Test (1)
Test (2)
Test (10)
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25f132f3777d6782a02341cbc4c3e517)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
declare @t table (title varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('InterSciences Competition (1)')
insert into @t values ('InterSciences Competition (10)')
insert into @t values ('InterSciences Competition (2)')


select * from @t
order by cast(replace(substring(title,CHARINDEX('(',title)+1,CHARINDEX(')',title)),')','') as INT)
```